# Loop through all the elements of an array into jsonb and modify values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgresql table with `jsonb` column `details`. One of the fields of this column contains an array with name `ranges`, each element of which can contain data in a decimal value. I need to turn all these values into integers (i.e. multiply the values by 100) and remove key `unit`. However, these fields can also be null. The array can be of any size.

Example of my `jsonb`:

```json
{
    "ranges": [
        {
            "types": {...},
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": "SQUARE",
                "range": {
                    "to": 25.399999618530273,
                    "from": 24.360000610351562
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "types": {...},
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": "SQUARE",
                "range": {
                    "to": 44.560001373291016,
                    "from": 31.969999313354492
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "types": {...},
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": "SQUARE",
                "range": {
                    "to": null,
                    "from": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": "SQUARE",
                "range": null
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": null
        }
    ],
    "...": {...}
}
```

I wrote a query that fetches the value of `to`, but it fetches a specific element of the array with 0 index. Is it possible to loop through all the elements of an array? How can I immediately change this value? Now in my request I just get it. Maybe there is a better way to solve my problem?

```
select details -> 'ranges' -> 0 -> 'areaRange' -> 'range' -> 'to'
from table_name
where details -> 'ranges' -> 0 -> 'areaRange' -> 'range' -> 'to' is not null
```

Function that rounds a number and multiplies by 100:

```
SELECT round( CAST(float8 '99.69999694824219' as numeric), 2) * 100; -- 9970
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to loop through all the elements of the array and update some elements of theme we can use `jsonb_array_elements` and `jsonb_set`.

`jsonb_array_elements` to expands a JSON array of objects to a set of objects. those objects will then be handled and updated by `jsonb_set` one by one, then grouped using aggregate function `json_agg` which aggregates record values as JSON.

```
UPDATE table_name t
SET details = jsonb_set(t.details::jsonb, '{ranges}', s.range_updated::jsonb)
FROM (
  SELECT details,
  jsonb_agg(
     jsonb_set(ranges::jsonb, '{areaRange,range,to}', 
      (round( CAST(ranges->'areaRange'->'range'->>'to' as numeric), 2) * 100)::varchar::jsonb
    )
  ) as range_updated
  FROM table_name ,
    jsonb_array_elements(details -> 'ranges') as ranges
  GROUP BY details
) s
WHERE t.details = s.details ;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qsAiUYwn)

Comment: thank you very much! it works wonderful! But why but are the values left with a fractional part? for example `55,28` is cast to `5528.00`. Maybe there is a way to make it exactly `5528`?

Comment: `select to_char((round( CAST('5528.00' as numeric), 2) * 1), 'FM999999999999')::varchar::jsonb;` - it helps me