# Loop through all the elements of an array into jsonb and delete keys

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgresql table with `jsonb` column `details`. One of the fields of this column contains an array with name `ranges`. I need to remove key `unit` for each element of this array. However, these fields can also be null. The array can be of any size.

Example of my `jsonb`:

```json
{
    "ranges": [
        {
            "...": {...},
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": "SQUARE",
                "...": {...}
            }
        },
        {
            "...": {...},
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": "SQUARE_2",
                "range": {...}
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": {
                "unit": null
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": null
        }
    ],
    "...": {...}
}
```

Comment: Use the same approach as for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75934270/1048572). Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonb_array_elements` To loop through all the elements of the array.

To remove an element from an object of objects we can use `#-` : `jsonb (ranges) #- '{areaRange,unit}'`

`jsonb_set` to update the json.

```
UPDATE table_name t
SET details = jsonb_set(t.details::jsonb, '{ranges}', s.range_updated::jsonb)
FROM (
  SELECT details,
  jsonb_agg(
       jsonb (ranges) #- '{areaRange,unit}'
  ) as range_updated
  FROM table_name ,
    jsonb_array_elements(details -> 'ranges') as ranges
  GROUP BY details
) s
WHERE t.details = s.details ;

SELECT jsonb_pretty(details) FROM table_name
```

Result :

```
{
    "ranges": [
        {
            "areaRange": {
                "range": {
                    "to": 25.399999618530273,
                    "from": 24.360000610351562
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": {
                "range": {
                    "to": 44.560001373291016,
                    "from": 31.969999313354492
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": {
                "range": {
                    "to": null,
                    "from": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": {
            }
        },
        {
            "areaRange": null
        }
    ]
}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BhCxRufU)

Comment: thanks for your explanation. now I understand how to use `#-`